# What is the wisest way to spend your unicoins?

Tags: feature-request, unicoins, april-fools

I have mined unicoins for hours and now want to use them wisely.

I was thinking of betting in the fastest answering user. However, I believe this is not implemented yet. In what version of stack overflow will this be possible?

Also, do you have an API for automated trading of unicoins?

Comment: Save them till the exchange rate goes up - forecasts are that it will explode after today!

Comment: Sure, just buy the powerup... oh. wait.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there's no trading.

*However*, if someone comes up with a good contest here on Meta where they offer some of their own Unicoins to the winner, I'd be open to holding the amount in escrow and award it to the winner. Sort of like a bounty, just in Unicoins.

It has to be funny though, as determined by me.

Answer (score 2):

Some say, that if you get to exactly **1337 Unicoins**, you'll get the extremely rare and exclusive **Super Unicorn Platinum Badge** (on every Stackexchange Profile).

Answer (score 1):

Carfully using them to increase your status in the network. That means: on reputation, appearance and of course, **enlightenment**.

Answer (score 0):

Sell them at an inflated price on eBay!